# How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-16 LE file in C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I have a UTF-16 LE file and at the beginning it has a BOM.

How do I remove this using C++? I've seen many Python examples.

Ultimately I would like it to be a UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-16 LE file in C++?

The size of UTF-16 BOM is 2 bytes. You can remove the BOM by copying all bytes except the first two that contain the BOM into a new file. Replace the old file with the new.

Comment: But mine contains just one BOM, which is FEFF in hex, 65279 in decimal.

Comment: And how would I do a bit-shift on a character array? I have `for (INT i=0;i<wcslen(sStr);i++) sStr[i] = sStr[i+1];` which isn't too efficient!

Comment: @JeffR You don't need to "bit-shift". Why do you think that's inefficient?

Comment: I thought there might be a one-function lower-level function to do it.

Comment: @JeffR There isn't.